# Jquery Sortable -> Placeholder width on first item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working one one page, where you have to be able to drag items to sort them. Everything works, but placeholder itself is bit buggy. On first item its wider than it should be, but on third, fourth etc. item its ok.

Adding images so you can see what I mean.

Also, this is the part of sortable code I am using:

```
$(".content-page").sortable({
    start: function(e,ui){
        ui.placeholder.height($(this).find(".sorted-icons").first().outerHeight(true));
        ui.placeholder.width($(this).find(".sorted-icons").first().outerWidth(true));
    },
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    items: '.sorted-icons:not(.new_icon)',
```

CSS

```
.placeholder{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

As you can see, I take the dimensions of first image and set placeholders dimensions to that image. It always takes the first one.

Does somebody know where is the problem?

Images:
[image][image]

**//Edit:**

I found out, that when I use:

```
ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.width());
```

All dem items have same width problem as first one. So it looks like it derps the size when it takes the size of itself, being dragged.

Some ideas?

Comment: It would help if we could see some CSS?

Comment: @Jackhardcastle What CSS exactly do you want? There is really not a lot of usefull CSS for this at all. The div that image is in has width of image itself. The placeholder has dimensions of image too. By my testing there is some problem with getting the size of image that is sortable. But I added the CSS of placeholder itself.

Comment: You should inspect this in the browser to easily determine what is styling this larger than the others.

Comment: You do not understand. It takes the size of image itself and applies it to placeholder. Size of all images is 311x311px. I tried the code that takes the size of item thats being sorted (the code after //Edit: part) and with that, every signle placeholder was wider than it should. So there is some problem in jQuery when taking the size of image, thats being dragged/sorted.